# What is the proper translation/name of Jesus Christ in German?

Tags: person-names, latin, religion

I’ve seen *Jesus* (pronounced 'Yey-zoos, IPA: /ˈjeː.zʊs/) as the German name of Jesus ('Jee-zus /ˈdʒiː.zəs/), is that correct?

For Christ (Kryst /kraɪst/), I’ve seen *Christus* (Krist-oos /ˈkʀɪs.tʊs/), but Google Translate – obviously not the most reliable source – says *Christi* (Krist-ee /ˈkʀɪs.ti/) when used in certain sentences, and then there’s the feast called *Corpus Christi* ‘Fronleichnam’, so I’m a little confused.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Welcome to the German Language SE. Feel free to take the [tour]. If you need specific help, you'll most probably find it in the [help]. Have a nice day.

Comment: It's not Yey. You might consider using the IPA.

Comment: There is a common trick to answer such questions: Search for 'Jesus Christ' in Wikipedia (en), from there go to the German page; voila: Jesus Christus.  Voted to close because of general reference ... - and no, Google-Translate is obviously one of the poorest sources.

Comment: @CarstenS I’ve added IPA transcriptions. Anyway, _ey_ is indeed used by some English dictionaries for something like /eː/.

Comment: @userunknown The question is obviously more about the form _Christ**i**_ than _Christ**us**_. Wikipedia is quiet about that, but [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jesus_Christus) has a declension table, although without explanation for the alternative forms in Acc and Dat or the uncommon form in Gen. Other dictionaries are probably more verbose, but [Duden Online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Jesus_Christus) isn’t, for instance. Overall it’s a valid question as the answers show.

Comment: @Chrissov: So Wiktionary shows that 'Christi' is not the nominativ but genitiv. And Corpus Christi isn't the german name of the feast, but a genetiv form, too. I don't get your point. Duden has the Genetiv too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the cases in German closely correspond to the cases in Latin, and since the Latin language is such a significant cultural possession of the Roman Catholic church, the name "Jesus Christus" is often declined in German according to the case endings in Latin.

The Latin case endings are:

- Nominative: Jesus Christus
- Genitive: Jesu Christi
- Dative: Jesu Christo
- Accusative: Jesum Christum
- Ablative: Jesu Christo
- Vocative: Jesu Christe

Thus while "Christus" is nominative, you may hear of the "Himmelfahrt Christi" (gen.), or see something dated "nach Christo" (dat.), or "vor Geburt Christi" (gen. again), while the Bach cantata "Komm, Jesu, Komm" (voc.) employs the vocative case which Latin uses for directly addressing somebody, even though no such case exists in German.

Comment: Actually, "Jesus" is declined using a mixture of Latin and Greek forms (the accusative follows the Latin pattern, the others the Greek pattern). The declination forms for "Christus" are Latin.

Comment: Well, Ἰησοῦς is after all not a Greek name but a Greek transliteration of a Hebrew name, and Jesus is a Latinization of Ἰησοῦς, so the unusual-looking Latin case endings are of course modeled on the unusual-looking Greek ones. But this is still the normal way of declining Jesus in Latin, and the spelling used in German (J for initial iota, ū for οῦ) shows that all the forms were overtaken from the Latin—that is, from the Latinized forms of the awkwardly Hellenized Hebrew name—and that none of the German forms come directly from the Greek.

Comment: That's right. I just wanted to give an explanation to those readers who were puzzled because their old Latin school grammar book didn't mention an -u genitive.

Comment: Since singular (masculine) nouns and names usually get a suffix only in the genitive case, it‘s not too surprising that almost everyone uses the nominative form _Jesus Christus_ for accusative and dative as well – nowadays.

Comment: Random anecdote: I wrote *Jesus’* for the genitive in a test in German RE once and my teacher corrected it into *Jesu*, so the Germanic case-forming rules are obviously considered inacceptable for *Jesus*.

Answer (score 6):

Normally you would use *Jesus Christus*. 
So you would say:

> Das ist Jesus Christus. (This is Jesus Christ)

The genitive is *Jesu Christi*, retaining the Latin form:

> Das ist einer der Jünger Jesu Christi. (This is an apostle of Jesus Christ.)
>
> Der gehört zu Christi Jüngern. (That one is one of Christ's disciples.)

Either is often shortened to a simple *Jesus* or *Christus* (resp. *Jesu*, *Christi*)

> nach Christi Geburt, Jesu Zeiten

In older texts and songs (e.g. Luther) you can also encounter `Immanuel`. I don't really know why, but it is the same person...

As for the pronunciation: **'Yey-zoos** seems about right.

Comment: "Seht, die Jungfrau wird ein Kind empfangen, einen Sohn wird sie gebären, und man wird ihm den Namen Immanuel geben, das heißt übersetzt: Gott ist mit uns." Mt. 1,23.

Comment: @Veredomon ja, aber warum wurde da Immanuel gesagt und nicht Jesus?

Comment: Der Prophet Jesaia sagte in Jes 7,14 die Geburt eines Immanuels durch eine Jungfrau vorher, und da Jesus Christus von einer Jungfrau geboren wurde, ist er folglich auch Immanuel. Damit stellt Matthäus Jesus als den prophezeiten Immanuel dar.

Comment: @Veredomon Ahh, OK, vielen dank.