# Using the genitive form of Christus in German

Tags: genitive, person-names, possessive, religion

I recently asked a [question regarding the proper German translation of Jesus Christ](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28500/what-is-the-proper-translation-name-of-jesus-christ-in-german). I was told that Christ was *Christus*, and the genitive form was *Christi*. So I would just like some help understanding exactly how the genitive form works. This is probably really simple, but I just want to be sure. Thanks for your help in advance.

Are all of these proper translations, and using the genitive form correctly? If not, can you please correct them?

- *The hands of Christ/Die Hände Christi* (A physical part of Christ)
- *The robe of Christ/Das Gewand Christi* (A physical property belonging to Christ)
- *The kiss of Christ/Der Kuss Christi* (A conceptual noun pertaining to Christ)
- *The disciple of Christ/Der Jünger Christi* (Another person that does not literally *belong* to Christ)

Comment: You could of course also use the genitive as possessive attribute preceding the noun, _Christi Hände_, or you could use _von_ plus dative, _die Hände von Christus_ (nobody uses or expects the Latin inflection in dative and accusative any more), or sometimes even a compound, _das Christusgewand_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see as a german native, your translations are correct. Also, the genitive (and other cases) of Christus are based on [the Latin -o declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension#Second_declension_.28o.29). This usually happens, when you are using words which have a Latin orgin.

For further explanations you can also look up [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/12058/20692) by [Hubert Schölnast](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1487/hubert-sch%C3%B6lnast).

Answer (score 0):

Well done, all translations are correct.